Validity of quaternion derivative from Sachs?
I'm reading General Relativity and Matter by Mendel Sachs.  This work is a bit controversial overall, but for this question I'm interested in a specific construction from Section 3.13 "Quaternion Calculus".
That starts with this statement:

It was emphasized earlier that the invariant differential interval of a Riemannian space-time, in the quaternion calculus, is itself a quaternion, $d\mathcal{I} = q^\mu dx_\mu$, rather than the real number, $ds = \pm( g^{\mu\nu} dx_\mu dx_\nu )^{1/2}$.

In that expression, each $q^\mu = q^\mu(x)$ for $\mu \in \{0,1,2,3\}$ is a quaternion and the Einstein summation convention is used.
He later continues to define a "quaternion total derivative" $d/d\mathcal{I} = (q^\mu)^{-1} d/dx_\mu$ where $(q^\mu)^{-1}$ is the quaternion inverse of $q^\mu$ for each value of $\mu$.

Thus, by definition, if $F(\mathcal{I})$ is a functional form in terms of $\mathcal{I}$, $$\frac{dF(\mathcal{I})}{d\mathcal{I}} = \lim_{\Delta x_\mu \rightarrow 0} \left[ \frac{F(\mathcal{I} + \Delta \mathcal{I}) - F(\mathcal{I})}{\Delta x_\mu} \right] (q^\mu)^{-1}(x).$$ This is analogous to the definition of the derivative of a complex variable, $df(z)/dz$, in the complex plane.  Here, if $f(z)$ is analytic in the domain where $df/dz$ is evaluated, its value is independent of any particular path in $z$-space along which the increment $dz$ may be defined.  Similarly, in the quaternion calculus, $dF/d\mathcal{I}$ is defined on the domain of quaternion space where $F$ is non-singular and the derivatives are path-independent.

This definition of "total quaternion derivative" is different than any I've seen in the past (e.g. Derivative of quaternions) because the term in brackets is a ratio of real-numbers prior to taking the limit instead of being a ratio of quaternions or, at least, the ratio of a real number to a quaternion.  I suspect that's enough to support the "path-independent" portion of the claim, but I doubt that it is analogous to the complex derivative in any meaningful way.  I'm aware at a surface level, however, that there is a notion of analyticity for quaternions, so I'm not sure if this specific definition is meaningful in that context.
Is this a common, valid, or useful definition of "total quaternion derivative" that has the properties analogous to the complex derivative as claimed?  A proof, counterexample, or reference would be appreciated.  This seems to be a less-well studied topic than some, and I'm having trouble finding the right place or terms to grab onto it, assuming that it's valid at all.

If the $q^\mu$ form an orthogonal basis $\mathrm{Re}(\bar q^\mu q^\nu) = 0$, $\nu\ne\mu$, then if I am understanding correctly this is quite reasonable. It's really just the quaternion $\nabla$ operator, and if you let it act via quaternion multiplication on quaternion-valued functions there are strong parallels with complex derivatives. In particular, the analogue of an analytic function is a quaternion valued $Q(\mathcal I)$ where $\nabla Q(\mathcal I) = 0$; I would call this is a (left) monogenic function and, for example, it ought to satisfy a version of Cauchy's formula.

What's confusing to me is the use of $x$. For this to make sense, they ought to be the coefficients of the $q^\mu$ basis, but then why are they also parameterizing $q^\mu$?

The only stated restriction on the $q^\mu(x)$ when they are introduced is that they "are a set of four quaternion fields that transform in space-time as a four-vector under the Einstein group.  He works in the $2 \times 2$ matrix representation of the quaternions and derives $q^\mu \tilde{q}\mu = -4 I{2 \times 2}$ with the tilde the conjugate formed by reversing the sign of the real part of the quaternion.

His overall program is to get a "square root" representation of the metric tensor, which comes to $g^{\mu\nu} = -(1/2) (q^\mu \tilde{q}^\nu + q^\nu \tilde{q}^\mu)$.  Since it's general rather than special relativity, that construction is a function of position in spacetime. I will think on whether that is equivalent to the orthonormal basis condition that you mentioned @NicholasTodoroff.  Seems like it might at first glance.

A side note, but if you're interested in these sorts of ideas then what you really want is gauge theory gravity or just geometric algebra applied to standard GR. These do exactly the same "square root of the metric", as such an equation is exactly the defining equation of a geometric/Clifford algebra (which quaternions are an example of).

Back on topic: I think the issue is that he hasn't defined $\mathcal I$. It somehow depends on $x$, and he's really taking derivatives with respect to $x$ and not $\mathcal I$ itself. But that's nonsense if the relationship between $x$ and $\mathcal I$ isn't specified.

I had look at the book; I'm am fairly confident my first comment is correct, but it doesn't look like he uses the damn thing anywhere! What was the point of talking about it, then? Anyway, he uses the strange phrase "local limit" to refer to choosing orthonormal coordinates; in (3.64) he requires that the $q^\mu$ are orthonormal "in the local limit", which seems to mean $x_\nu$ orthonormal $\implies q^\mu$ orthonormal. He doesn't say they're always orthonormal, though, and in the case they are not the his expression for $d/d\mathcal I$ makes no sense.

As for what's going on with $\mathcal I$, I'm pretty sure he intends it as an arbitrary quaternion variable and that $\Delta\mathcal I = q^\mu\Delta x_\mu$. The position $x$ itself is completely irrelevant, and the derivative is defined pointwise; you could just as well define this derivative without any mention of spatial points or coordinates and it would be 1000x clearer. This again squares with my first comment.
